# AWS Amplify Datastore doesn't work in production

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I have an expo app that works fine in development mode but once installed on an actual device, none the queries performed on the Amplify Datastore works. I tried adding `Datastore.configure` but It still doesn't work. I heard installing the unstable version of Datastore `npm install @aws-amplify/datastore@unstable` could also make it work but that didn't work either.

Here's a sample of the code

```
import { useWindowDimensions, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "../aws-exports";
import { DataStore } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { House } from "../models";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import HouseMark from "../components/HouseMark";
import { mapStyle } from "../utils";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
DataStore.configure(awsconfig);

const SellScreen = () => {
  const [houses, setHouses] = useState();

  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      DataStore.query(House, (h) => h.available.eq(true)).then(setHouses);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);


  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView className=" flex-1">
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={{
          width,
          height,
        }}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 12.3637,
          longitude: -1.526,
          latitudeDelta: 0.7,
          longitudeDelta: 0.7,
        }}
      >
    
        {houses &&
          houses.map((house, id) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={id}>
              <HouseMark house={house} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
      </MapView>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default SellScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your amplify as this :

```js
  import { Amplify } from "@aws-amplify/core";
  import {
    AuthModeStrategyType,
    DataStore,
  } from "aws-amplify";
  import config from "../src/aws-exports";

  
  Amplify.configure(config);

  DataStore.configure({
    ...config,
    authModeStrategyType: AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH,
  });

  DataStore.start().catch(() => {
    DataStore.clear().then(() => {
      DataStore.start();
    });
  });
```